# How to create deciles?

Tags: sql-server

I have a sales data. I need to divide the sales into equal 10 buckets and assign a decile number accordingly. The range of the data is from 0 to 1000. I want to create the buckets like following:

```
0-100   as decile 1
101-200 as decile 2
201-300 as decile 3
and so on till 1000 i.e. till decile 10.
```

How to achieve the same without specifying any value explicitly?

Comment: I would look into NTILE(): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the output by using **`NTILE`**. Here in your current scenario If the bucket is 10 then the query can be:

```
SELECT CAST(MIN(Tbl.Col1) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '-' + CAST(MAX(Tbl.Col1) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Range, Tbl.Tile AS Decile
FROM (
        SELECT Col1, NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY Col1) Tile
        FROM @t
    ) Tbl
GROUP BY Tbl.Tile
```

The outupt for the query is :

```
Range     Decile
1-100       1
101-200     2
201-300     3
301-400     4
401-500     5
501-600     6
601-700     7
701-800     8
801-900     9
901-1000    10
```

if the bucket change then you can do this by changing in **`NTILE(10)`** to your number of bucket.

Comment: Works perfectly as per what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible approaches, using `ROW_NUMBER()` or `NTILE()`. The next example demonstrates the differences between these approaches. If you have 950 items and you use `NTILE()`, the result is 10 buckets with 95 items (1...95, 96...190, ..., 856...950). With `ROW_NUMBER()` the result is 10 buckets, 9 of them with 100 items, and the last one with 50 items (1...100, 101...200, ..., 901...950)

Note, that if the order is important, you need to use an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause instead of `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`:

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) / 100 + 1) AS [RowNo],
   NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS TileNo
FROM 
   YourTable
```

Result:

```
---------------------
       RowNo   TileNo
---------------------
1      1       1
2      1       1
...            
94     1       1
95     1       2
96     1       2
97     1       2
98     1       2
99     1       2
100    2       2
101    2       2
...            
900    9       10
901    10      10
902    10      10
...            
950    10      10
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly when we know the size i.e. 100 in prior.

Comment: Okay sure will try this too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee that the buckets are always consistent you will need to specify the values that define the buckets or a function that produces them.  If, however, you are happy with some potential variance depending on your data, you can use the [`ntile`](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-ntile-function/) function to assign a partitioned row number based on the amount of data returned in your query.

If you actually have a value in your dataset that is a number between `0` and `1000` that you want to sort into decile buckets, this is a trivial bit of arithmetic:

```
-- cte generates a row with each number between 0 and 1000
with n(n) as (select n from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as n(n))
    ,v(v) as (select top (1001) row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 from n n1, n n2, n n3, n n4)
select v
      ,((v-1)/100)+1 as Decile
      ,ntile(10) over (order by v) as tile
from v;
```

## Output

```
+------+--------+------+
|  v   | Decile | tile |
+------+--------+------+
|    0 |      1 |    1 |
|    1 |      1 |    1 |
|  ... |    ... |  ... |
|  100 |      1 |    1 |
|  101 |      2 |    2 |
|  ... |    ... |  ... |
|  ... |    ... |  ... |
|  900 |      9 |    9 |
|  901 |     10 |   10 |
|  ... |    ... |  ... |
|  999 |     10 |   10 |
| 1000 |     10 |   10 |
+------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly when we know the size i.e. 100 in prior.

Comment: @Keval  I don't understand your comment, especially as the answer you selected as correct is the same as the `tile` column in mine.

Comment: Sorry. Actually "((v-1)/100)+1 as Decile" becomes static. If the range of my data will change then I need to take care of the /100 value.

Comment: @Keval My answer also included the `ntile` option.